# Powershell Write-Progress bar not working on large files

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with the write-progress command in Powershell v. 1.0.  When I run this script on test directories containing a few hundred files in Powershell ISE the progress bar works as advertised and recursively displays the names of all the files therein.  When I run it on our company domain with user home directories the progress bar does not move at all and $files.name only displays the top level directory names inside the folder such as "Desktop", "AppData", etc.  Any ideas on why this might be the case?  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$path = "\\company\shares\campus\HomeDir\username"    
$dest = "R:\Terminated"    
$counter = 0    
$files = gci $path -recurse            
Foreach($file in $files)
         {
          Copy-Item $path $dest -recurse -force
          Write-Progress -Activity "Backing Up Terminated User HomeDir:" -status $file.name -PercentComplete ($counter / $files.count*100) 
          $counter++           
          }

         If ($Counter = $files.Count)
          {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Backup Complete.")} 
         Else 
          {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("File Backup Did Not Finish.")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably doing this because you're copying both files and directories. The `$files` variable contains both directory and file results. If you want to filter out the directories, and copy the files as individual items, filter out the directory results.

When you call `Copy-Item` inside the `foreach` loop, if it binds `-Path` to a directory, then the single `Copy-Item` command will encompass an entire directory structure worth of files. That's why you're not getting status on a per-file basis.

```
$files = gci $path -recurse | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer; };
```

Comment: @user3311261: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as you deem appropriate :)